# Error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar procedure

Tags: sql-server

Table viewgroup

```
NO_induk  |  Gaji_bulan
-----------------------                     
200012    |      012017                                                   
200012    |      022017                      
200012    |      122017               
200006    |      012017           
200006    |      022017           
200006    |      122017              
2000AA    |      012017          
2000AA    |      022017          
2000AA    |      122017             

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcgroup]

@no_induk1 nvarchar(50),

@no_induk2 nvarchar(50),

@bulan1 nvarchar(6),

@bulan2 nvarchar(6)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(gaji_bulan) + ',' FROM (select distinct gaji_bulan from tblgaji_detail ) as tmp order by gaji_bulan
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols))  

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    select no_induk,nama_pelamar,kodept,namapt,kodetp,ket, nilai_ahir, gaji_bulan from View_group where
    no_induk>='+@no_induk1+' and no_induk<='+@no_induk2+' 
    and gaji_bulan>='+@bulan1+' and gaji_bulan<='+@bulan2+' 

) src
pivot 
(
    max(nilai_ahir) for gaji_bulan in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
END
```

If I execute the procedure like this, it's running well:

```
exec prcgroup '200006','200006','012017','122017'
```

I have a problem if I execute it like this:

```
exec prcgroup '200006','2000AA','012017','122017'
```

> Error 
>   Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2000AA' to data type int.

I expected it to run like this:

```
prcgroup '200006','2000AA','012017','122017'
```

Comment: What is the meaning of '2000AA' in 'NO_induk' column?

Comment: what is the datatype of 'no_induk' column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing string so it must be decorated by SingleQuote(`'`). So after `>=` conditions you have to use `'''+@no_induk2+'''` instead of `'+@no_induk2+'`.
Updated your query like below:

```
set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    select no_induk,nama_pelamar,kodept,namapt,kodetp,ket, nilai_ahir, gaji_bulan from View_group where
    no_induk>='''+@no_induk1+''' and no_induk<='''+@no_induk2+''' 
    and gaji_bulan>='''+@bulan1+''' and gaji_bulan<='''+@bulan2+''' 

) src
pivot 
(
    max(nilai_ahir) for gaji_bulan in (''' + @cols + ''')
) piv'
```